# How to combine two columns into one column with no repeating values in python using pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

How do I perform the following dataframe operation going from Dataframe A to dataframe B in pandas for python? I have tried pivot and groupby but I keep getting errors. Any support is greatly appreciated.

DataFrame A

| Col A | Col B |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 |
| 100 | 2 |
| 200 | 3 |
| 200 | 4 |

DataFrame B

| Col A & B |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 100 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 200 |

Comment: What if the second 100 rows was after the 200 rows? Would you have the same output?

Comment: No I don't want any duplicates

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question but check my answer and comment if needed ;)

Comment: Oh my apologies. I just reread what you were saying. so youre below solution is awesome but just for learning sake what would it look like if the second 100 was after the 200? How would that change the solution?

Comment: That was my question, what would be the expected output in this case? Does order matter? In any case I provided several alternatives.

Comment: thank you so much. this is a huge learning point for me that I have spent days on. I can't tell you how much I appreciate it!

Comment: You're welcome, next time don't hesitate to provide your own attempt, you might get pointers on why your code failed

Comment: Sorry to be a bother but would you mind explaining to me when slicing with d.iloc you use : and ::-1. i know that ::-1 means reverse but why do you need both in this case? I realize this is very elementary for most.

Comment: of course, this is just to reverse the order of the columns before `unstack` to match your desired output. I suggest you try with and without reversing the order and also comparing `stack` and `unstack` to appreciate the different orders.

Answer (score 1):

One option using [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
out = (df
   .groupby('Col A', group_keys=False, sort=False)
   .apply(lambda d: d.iloc[:, ::-1].unstack().drop_duplicates())
   .reset_index(drop=True).to_frame(name='Col A&B')
)
```

Another with [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
out = (pd
   .concat([df['Col B'], df['Col A'].drop_duplicates(keep='last')])
   .sort_index().reset_index(drop=True).to_frame(name='Col A&B')
)
```

output:

```
   Col A&B
0        1
1        2
2      100
3        3
4        4
5      200
```

If order does not matter, you can [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
out = df.stack().drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True).to_frame(name='Col A&B')
```

output:

```
   Col A&B
0      100
1        1
2        2
3      200
4        3
5        4
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
out = pd.DataFrame({'Col A&B': np.unique(df)})
out
```

Output:

```
   Col A&B
0        1
1        2
2        3
3        4
4      100
5      200
```